# Is there way to use `respected` in passive voice with object pronoun

Tags: expressions, passive-voice

I want to say that there two persons who came to do something and I highly respect them and I want to call them by name in the same sentence.
I thought it should be like this: "Deeply respected by me, Henry and Jack are well known, they came there to tell you something."
or
"Well known people Henry and Jack, deeply respected by me, came here to tell you something."

Comment: You mean, is it OK with no subject? In general, no.

Comment: @GEdgar thanks Edgar, may be you could show the most closet sentence structure to mine.

Comment: You could say "Henry is deeply respected by me, Henry, and Jack".  (Though putting "me" first is often frowned upon.)

Comment: @Hot Licks The first - do you mean as in your example, before `Henry and Jack`?

Comment: @RS - Yep.  "Proper" (starchy) English would go "Henry, Jack, and me" (or "Henry, Jack, and myself").

Comment: @Hot Licks or I could use "Henry and Jack, deeply respected by me, did this and this..." Right?

Comment: It all depends on who's doing the respecting of whom.  (Note that I accidentally duplicated "Henry" in the above example -- should have been "Sam is deeply respected by ...")

Comment: (Your original example makes it seem like the three of you are respecting someone/something not mentioned.)

Comment: @Hot Licks no, I deeply respect Henry and Jack, so they deeply respected (by whom? By me).

Comment: It would sort of work with a colon after "me".  Otherwise it's gibberish.

Comment: It's [nearly always ***highly** respected*,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=highly+respected%2Cdeeply+respected&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chighly%20respected%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeeply%20respected%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chighly%20respected%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeeply%20respected%3B%2Cc0) not ***deeply***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-experts in English: You will get into less trouble if you put the subject of the sentence first.

These are clumsy:

> Deeply respected by me, Henry and Jack are well known, they came there to tell you something.
>   Well known people Henry and Jack, deeply respected by me, came here to tell you something.

To make them clear, start with the subject:

> Henry and Jack, who are well known and deeply respected by me, came here to tell you something.

Another way to write clearly would be to separate it into two sentences.

> Henry and Jack came here to tell you something.  They are well known, and I deeply respect them.